# Folder Heirarchy in Sharepoint 2010 document library?

Tags: document-library, folder

How many nested folders can we have in document library in Sharepoint 2010?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a similar post in another forum that may answer your question - [Maximum number of folders.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010general/thread/d5346a1e-9c32-4045-84c1-600836177b7f) (You can have many, perhaps millions, but views & queries have limits).